# QueryDsl and EntityManager making an update using both

Tags: spring, jpa, querydsl

I wonder what is the difference between doing an update to an entity using the following methods:

1) With entityManager

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;


@Transactional
public void updateEntity(){
  entityManager.merge(entity);
}
```

2)With entityManager using queryDSL

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

private JPAQueryFactory query;

@PostConstruct
public void setUp(){
    query = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
}


@Transactional
public void updateEntity(Entity entity){
    QEntity qEntity = QEntity.entity;
    JPAUpdateClause update = new JPAUpdateClause(entityManager, qEntity);
    update.set(qEntity.subject, entity.getSubject()).where(qEntity.id.eq(entity.getId())).execute();
}
```

They both produces the same result. They update the entity correctly. But, what is the advantage using one over another? Or, what is the correct way to update the entity?

Comment: you mean like one is a standard API (so is portable), and the other isn't?

Comment: I mean on the behavior, performance and best practices